# How to get cell address of the last row in range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ToolDataExtract()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieves Target Folder From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension
  myExtension = "*.csv*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile, UpdateLinks:=False)

'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

'Data Extracted from Files
'Find Last Row on Excel Data

s = Range("AE2")             'THIS RANGE WILL CHANGE

Dim cellAddress As String
cellAddress = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address

f1a = Range("R2")
f1b = Range("N2")
f1c = Range("O2")
f1d = Range("Q2")
f1e = Range("S2")
f1f = Range("P2")
f1g = Range("H2")
f1h = Range("" & cellAddress & "")


'Data Pasted into Excel File
Workbooks("file2").Worksheets("WMI LOG").Activate
Range("A1:H1") = Array("T", "H", "I", "P", "W", "O", "X1", "X2")
Cells(s + 1, 1) = f1a
Cells(s + 1, 2) = f1b
Cells(s + 1, 3) = f1c
Cells(s + 1, 4) = f1d
Cells(s + 1, 5) = f1e
Cells(s + 1, 6) = f1f
Cells(s + 1, 7) = f1g
Cells(s + 1, 8) = f1h

'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
      DoEvents

 wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop

'Message Box when tasks are completed
  MsgBox "Task Complete"

'Reset Macro Settings
ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address`?

Comment: I'll amend @BigBen 's answer to `Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address`

Comment: @PeterT : `Rows.Count` returns the same number for any sheet... No sense to amend it.

Comment: @PeterT that didn’t work

Comment: And what @BigBen suggested did not work? It works! But `lr` must be declared as a string.

Comment: `Dim cellAddress as String`, `cellAddress = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address`... `Range.Address` returns a `String`, not a `Long`.

Comment: For some reason it’s giving me the address of the first row instead

Comment: Then you don't have anything in column 8.

Comment: I have no idea what you might do. You've been given the solution and don't seem willing or able to provide any information that might help resolve matters.

Comment: s = Range("AE2")   
Dim cellAddress As String
cellAddress = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address(0, 0)
f1a = Range("R2")
f1b = Range("N2")
f1c = Range("O2")
f1d = Range("Q2")
f1e = Range("S2")
f1f = Range("P2")
f1g = Range("H2")
f1h = Range("" & cellAddress & "")
Workbooks("file2").Worksheets("WMI LOG").Activate

Comment: so it goes to a folder and opens each file in the folder. it pulls data from certain cells and i would like the address of the last cell in column H

Comment: so variable f1h is assigned a range with the cellAddress. but for some reason the value for H2 is displayed. every column has more than 3k values in to

Comment: my bad @SJR. is that enough info?

Comment: `cellAddress = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address` - `Sheet1` is a worksheet in `ThisWorkbook`, not each workbook that you open.

Answer (score 1):

Skip getting the row number, just:

```
Sub simple()
    MsgBox Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

[image]